# ember.js clearInterval not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js, setinterval, clearinterval

```
App.Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    timerStart: function () {


        this.timer = setInterval(this.ctimer, 1000);


    },


    timerEnd: function () {

        this.clearInterval(this.ctimer);

    },

    ctimer: function () {

        var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("timeBar").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();

       }
});
```

in ember.js, the clearInterval function not working as I call the timerEnd function.

what is right way to fix the problem on this code. Thank you.

Comment: Typo, it should be: this.clearInterval(this.timer);

Comment: You should probably use http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the timer variable and clearing that one instead of the ctimer. (Not tested)

```
App.Controller = Ember.ObjectController.extend({  
  timer: null,
  timerStart: function () {
      this.timer = setInterval(this.ctimer, 1000);
  },
  timerEnd: function () {
      this.clearInterval(this.timer);
  },
  ctimer: function () {
      var d = new Date();
      document.getElementById("timeBar").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Caqu, it works well!! after remove this in TimerEnd fuction.