# Emberjs Countdown - not stoppable

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Heyho

I have a little issue with my countdown written in Ember. More precisely in stopping my counter when it hits 0.

First of all... I'm using

*Ember Version*

```
DEBUG: Ember                    : 1.12.0
```

I've created a 'service' Class with some simple methods to handle the countdown process.

```
interval: function() {
  return 10; // Time between polls (in ms)
}.property().readOnly(),

totalTime: function() {
  return 5000; // Total Time (in ms)
}.property(),

timeDiff: 0,
timeLeft: function() {
  return Math.floor((this.get('totalTime') - this.get('timeDiff')) / 1000);
}.property('timeDiff'),

hasFinished: function() {
  return this.get('timeLeft') === 0;
}.property('timeLeft'),


// Schedules the function `f` to be executed every `interval` time.
schedule: function(f) {
  return Ember.run.later(this, function() {
    f.apply(this);
    this.set('timer', this.schedule(f));
  }, this.get('interval'));
},


// Starts the countdown, i.e. executes the `onTick` function every interval.
start: function() {
  this.set('startedAt', new Date());
  this.set('timer', this.schedule(this.get('onTick')));
},


// Stops the countdown
stop: function() {
  Ember.run.cancel(this.get('timer'));
},


onTick: function() {
  let self = this;
  self.set('timeDiff', new Date() - self.get('startedAt'));
  if (self.get('hasFinished')) {
    // TODO: Broken - This should stop the countdown :/
    self.stop();
  }
}
```

[CountDown with Ember.run.later()](https://gist.github.com/tzhbami7/982698edca77052f3f9e)

I'm starting the countdown within my controller (play action).
The countdown counts down as it should but it just doesn't stop :(

The self.stop() call in onTick() just doesn't do anything at all...

I tried to stop the countdown with an other action in my controller and that is working as it should :/

Any ideas how to solve that problem??

Cheers Michael

Comment: [Might be related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688238/ember-js-clearinterval-not-working)

Comment: Heyho - thx for the link. I already have a working solution with setInterval [gist](https://gist.github.com/tzhbami7/065bd41f1d45d20dd7e5) I tried to migrate it to Ember.run.later() since I've heard that it's bad practice to use setInterval

Comment: Does it call self.stop() correctly? If not make sure that hasFinished equals zero at some point otherwise it will continue on if it skips over zero for any reason. Maybe try <= instead.

Comment: It goes into stop(), I've already checked that with a console.log - Ember.run.cancel(...) doesn't cancel the loop :/ I'm starting to belive that I have access to the wrong timer in this.get('timer') - Am I doing something wrong in start() or schedule()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the courtesy or writing a Countdown service based on the code you have provided that allows you to start, reset and stop the countdown. My code assumes you are using Ember CLI, but I have included a JSBin that takes older ES5 syntax into account.

`app/services/countdown.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { get, set, computed, run } = Ember;

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  init() {
    set(this, 'totalTime', 10000);
    set(this, 'tickInterval', 100);
    set(this, 'timer', null);
    this.reset();
  },

  remainingTime: computed('elapsedTime', function() {
    const remainingTime = get(this, 'totalTime') - get(this, 'elapsedTime');
    return (remainingTime > 0) ? remainingTime : 0;
  }),

  hasFinished: computed('remainingTime', function() {
    return get(this, 'remainingTime') === 0;
  }),

  reset() {
    set(this, 'elapsedTime', 0);
    set(this, 'currentTime', Date.now());
  },

  start() {
    this.stop();
    set(this, 'currentTime', Date.now());
    this.tick();
  },

  stop() {
    const timer = get(this, 'timer');

    if (timer) {
      run.cancel(timer);
      set(this, 'timer', null);
    }
  },

  tick() {
    if (get(this, 'hasFinished')) {
      return;
    }

    const tickInterval = get(this, 'tickInterval');
    const currentTime = get(this, 'currentTime');
    const elapsedTime = get(this, 'elapsedTime');
    const now = Date.now();

    set(this, 'elapsedTime', elapsedTime + (now - currentTime));
    set(this, 'currentTime', now);
    set(this, 'timer', run.later(this, this.tick, tickInterval));
  }
});
```

I've made an example of this implementation [available on JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bajibefedo/edit?html,js,output) for you to toy around with.

Comment: Holy moly :P Thx a lot!!  I'll take a look at it in a bit.